# How to specify custom rendering template for options in {{selectmenu}} tag

Tags: jsviews, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I am looking for an example where I can specify template for rendering options, so that I can render an option as a two part: span with a background color and a value.

Simillar to this https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#custom_render

is this supported in the jsviews tag implementation?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably other approaches, including making your own custom tag - not using jQuery UI, or creating a derived version of the `{{selectmenu}}` tag control [here](https://www.jsviews.com/#samples/tag-controls/jqui/selectmenu), `{{myselectmenu}}` (using [baseTag](https://www.jsviews.com/#tagsapi@basetag)).

But here is a quick suggestion of one way you can do it:

```
{^{selectmenu person name="person" onBind=~onbind}}
  {^{for people}}
    <option data-style="{{:style}}" value="{{:id}}">{{:name}}</option>
  {{/for}}
{{/selectmenu}}
```

Data:

```
people: [
  {name: "John Resig", id: "1", style: "background-image: url(...);"},
  ...
```

Code:

```
pageTmpl.link("#page", model, {
  onbind: function(val) {
    // override onBind for this tag control instance
    this.baseApply(arguments);

    // override _renderItem for this widget instance:
    this.widget._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        var li = $( "<li>" ),
          wrapper = $( "<div>", { text: item.label } );

        if ( item.disabled ) {
          li.addClass( "ui-state-disabled" );
        }

        $( "<span>", {
          style: item.element.attr( "data-style" ),
          "class": "ui-icon " + item.element.attr( "data-class" )
        })
          .appendTo( wrapper );

        return li.append( wrapper ).appendTo( ul );
      };
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I ended up going with your quick suggestion, which worked well.